# Has anyone used Vertx for their production applications?

Tags: vert.x

Are the production operations really easy, given that it supports auto scaling, service registration and discovery. How good is the performance?

Comment: Have you seen the page: http://vertx.io/whos_using/ All companies listed use vert.x either internally or externally I guess you could try to reach to any of those for they success stories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked for a company that has been running Vert.x in production for a few years now. It ran pretty well, although we didn't use any of the auto scaling, serice registration and discovery features (those are relatively new). We had it running on the AWS cloud and handled scaling there.

I've shared our experiences with Vert.x in production on a few conferences, you can find a recent recording for the vJUG24 at https://youtu.be/aW4ewPCHbJc.